# What's the right way to install gems in a GC Patched ruby?

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, rubygems, patch, memory-profiling

I want to install a GC Patched Ruby to do a memory profiling on my app. I followed the instructions at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html#gc and installed a ruby instance at my home dir (I already have another "official" instance for development). This GC Patched ruby instance is working fine.

The problem is when I need to install gems to this instance, as the step 1.8.6 from the guide above tell me to do. I can't use the install of rubygems already on my machine, because it is pointing to other ruby instance. And I wasn't able to install another instance of rubygems just to my gc patched ruby.

That's why I want to know the right way to install rubygems on a GC patched ruby, in a machine that already have another install of non patched ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` environment variables to point to the directory you would like ruby to pull the gems from.

Also make sure the patched ruby binary appears before the other version in your `PATH` environment variable to ensure its picking up the correct version.